# How to connect to a SQL Server instance without knowing the Initial Catalog?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm writing a portable program that can be used on other computers as well as mine and It also connects to the SQL Database on that computer.
So the problem is that I don't have the database name of that computer. How can my program connect to that Database without previously knowing the database name?
In other words, I don't have enough information to create a complete **ConnectionString**.

Comment: If you want to connect to a database on the same computer as where the program is running, you can substitute the server name with just a dot: `.`

Comment: I think you've asked your question wrong, do you mean you don't know the Server's name?

Comment: How do I programmatically do this?

Comment: @keivanIpchi you can't connect to a database you dont know the name of. It's like me asking you what's my height? However if you DO know the Database Name and its the servers name you dont know you can use **.** instead of the server name in the connection string.

Comment: you need a connection string and proper authentication to connect to a db server. How do you know the proper db when the Db Name is not mentioned because tables can differ to db to db.? Hope if you explain what you want exactly we can provide a better approach.

Comment: Hard to undestand, I submited an edit, looks like OP does not know how to get info of the user databases a SQL Server instance has, so cannot build a proper connection string. How to connect to a SQL Server without knowing the databases? Easy, connect to a system database (called "master") and query what user databases exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to SQL Server's `master` database first.

Then, using this query, you can get data from databases in your database:
`SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases`

Using the site below, you can find the right Connection strings for you : 
https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dot in the connection string to represent.tbe local server.

Create a txt file, rename the extension to UDL. Open the UDL file and put a dot, a full stop:

[image]

If you have installed a SQL Instance (ie not the default instance) it will be **.\InstanceName**

Choose the Database drop down and click Test Connect.

Finally close the URL file and open it with NotePad and you will see the connection string.

Comment: I install the program an a computer using an installer. Then, I want the program to be able to connect to the database located on that computer. How do I do that?

Comment: Yup I know. I've read your question. I've asked a few things can you answer? Is the database yours? How do you know its SQL Server if you don't know the dB's name? How do you know the dB is installed?